# Replacing 3 lists with 2 generators

Tags: python, list, optimization, generator

I want to optimize my application using generators and instead of creating 3 lists I want to use 2 generators. Here's the short scheme of my app in it's current version:

1) Load data from a binary file -> 1st list

```
self.stream_data = [ struct.unpack(">H", data_file.read(2))[0] for foo in
                       xrange(self.columns*self.rows) ]
```

2) Create so called Nonzero-suppressed-data (all data with zeros) -> 2nd list

```
self.NZS_data = list()
for row in xrange(self.rows):
    self.NZS_data.append( [ self.stream_data[column + row * self.rows ] 
                          for column in xrange(self.columns) ] )
```

3) Create Zero-suppressed-data (without zeros with coordinates) -> 3rd list

```
self.ZS_data = list()
for row in xrange(self.rows):
    for column in xrange(self.columns):
        if self.NZS_data[row][column]:
            self.ZS_data.append( [ column, row, self.NZS_data[row][column] ] )
```

(I know that this could have been squeezed into a single list comprehension using itertools.product)

4) Save the ZS_data list into a file.

I used Python's cProfiler and most of the time (apart from reading and unpacking) is consumed for creation of these two (NZS_data and ZS_data) lists. Because I only need them for saving data into a file I've been thinking about using 2 generators:

1) Create a generator for reading a file -> 1st generator

```
self.stream_data = ( struct.unpack(">H", data_file.read(2))[0] for foo in
                       xrange(self.columns*self.rows) )
```

2) Create ZS_data generator (I don't really need this NZS data)

```
self.ZS_data = ( [column, row, self.stream_data.next()]
                 for row, column in itertools.product(xrange(self.rows),
                 xrange(self.columns))
                 if self.stream_data.next() )
```

**This of course won't work properly because I get two different values from the generator.**

3) Save data into a file using generator.

I wonder how this could be done. 
Maybe you have other ideas related to possible optimization of this application?

**ADDED**
*Solution based on a generator:*

```
def create_ZS_data(self):
    self.ZS_data = ( [column, row, self.stream_data[column + row * self.rows ]]
                     for row, column in itertools.product(xrange(self.rows), xrange(self.columns))
                     if self.stream_data[column + row * self.rows ] )
```

Profiler info:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     3257    1.117    0.000   71.598    0.022 decode_from_merlin.py:302(create_ZS_file)
   463419   67.705    0.000   67.705    0.000 decode_from_merlin.py:86(<genexpr>)
```

*Jon's Solution:*

```
create_ZS_data(self):
    self.ZS_data = list()
    for rowno, cols in enumerate(self.stream_data[i:i+self.columns] for i in xrange(0, len(self.stream_data), self.columns)):
        for colno, col in enumerate(cols):
            # col == value, (rowno, colno) = index
            if col:
                self.ZS_data.append([colno, rowno, col])
```

Profiler info:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     3257   18.616    0.006   19.919    0.006 decode_from_merlin.py:83(create_ZS_data)
```

Comment: Have you considered using `numpy` for this?

Comment: Do you mean using dtype/fromfile instead of struct?

Comment: Yup - then `reshape` it to row/column - then iterate over izip(*a.nonzero()) which will give you (row, col) tuples, using that to get the value, then write out whatever you want.

Comment: Just remembered `np.transpose(np.nonzero(a))` is better than `izip(*a.nonzero())`

Comment: Nice idea, I will definitely try it out however I just checked and we don't have numpy on our production server.

Comment: That's a shame - I'll just post some observations then...

Comment: Okay, added an answer with a couple of non-numpy suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possibly make the unpacking more efficient...

```
self.data_stream = struct.unpack_from('>{}H'.format(self.rows*self.columns), data_file)
```

The reduce the looping to something like:

```
for rowno, cols in enumerate(self.data_stream[i:i+self.columns] for i in xrange(0, len(self.data_stream), self.columns)):
    for colno, col in enumerate(cols):
        # col == value, (rowno, colno) = index
        if col == 0:
            pass # do something
        else:
            pass # do something else
```

**note - untested**

Comment: Wow, I'm shocked... Your solution is 10x faster than mine. Firstly, using unpack_from is much faster and I can see why, there's no iteration (3x faster in my case). But I cannot possibly understand why there's such an improvement with your loop. Could you please explain to me what's going on there?

Comment: @Wysek `unpack_from` returns a `tuple` and is being left as `tuple` instead of building a `list` as per original. The data is looped over only once, and slicing a portion of a tuple is a fast-op. For each row/col you conditionally check whether it's zero/nonzero/whatever, and do what's appropriate -- there's no appending elements to intermediate lists, then presumably looping over those *again*...

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but I'm just curious and want to learn something new :) I added two pieces of code, yours is almost 4 times faster. They use the same list self.stream_data and mine is purely based on generators. Where's the magic? Thank you so much for your solution and answers.

Comment: @Wysek There's always a little overhead for a listcomp/genexp, but not 4x - are you sure about your timings?

Comment: I just added a few lines from the profiler. I still have no idea why your code is so fast. My only guess is that calling generator so many times (463419) may cause an overhead, but I wouldn't expect it to be this big.

Comment: @Wysek to be honest I am not sure... I hope someone else with more experience could explain... I only wrote the code like that as it seemed to make sense... Sorry I can't help further