# Why loop over enumerate is so much faster then a generator?

Tags: python, optimization, generator, enumeration

Recently, I've discovered with the help of Jon Clements in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602396/replacing-3-lists-with-2-generators/1) thread that the following codes have very different execution times.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

*Comment:* self.stream_data is a vector tuple with many zeros and int16 values and create_ZS_data method is performing so called ZeroSuppression.

**Environment**
*Input:*     Many (3.5k) small files (~120kb each)
*OS:*        Linux64
*Python ver* 2.6.8

**Solution based on a generator:**

```
def create_ZS_data(self):
    self.ZS_data = ( [column, row, self.stream_data[column + row * self.rows ]]
                     for row, column in itertools.product(xrange(self.rows), xrange(self.columns))
                     if self.stream_data[column + row * self.rows ] )
```

*Profiler info:*

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     3257    1.117    0.000   71.598    0.022 decode_from_merlin.py:302(create_ZS_file)
   463419   67.705    0.000   67.705    0.000 decode_from_merlin.py:86(<genexpr>)
```

**Jon's Solution:**

```
create_ZS_data(self):
    self.ZS_data = list()
    for rowno, cols in enumerate(self.stream_data[i:i+self.columns] for i in xrange(0, len(self.stream_data), self.columns)):
        for colno, col in enumerate(cols):
            # col == value, (rowno, colno) = index
            if col:
                self.ZS_data.append([colno, rowno, col])
```

*Profiler info:*

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     3257   18.616    0.006   19.919    0.006 decode_from_merlin.py:83(create_ZS_data)
```

Comment: It seems fairly obvious that it has to do with the number of calls in the first solution, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but weren't generators born to deal with big number of calls? They are usually recommended as an alternative to big lists.

Comment: for simple cases, generators *generally* reduce memory usage at the cost of CPU.

Comment: Your first solution is not actually using a generator expression, but a list comprehension.

Comment: @hop: The list comprehension contains a generator expression as noted in the profiler info shown -- `itertools.product()` is a generator function.

Comment: @martineau: so? that is not really contradicting what i said…

Comment: @hop: My point is their first solution _is_ using a generator within the list comprehension. If you don't disagree, what was the point of your initial comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the prior discussion; you seem to be troubled that your clever comprehension isn't as efficient in cycles as it is in characters of source code. What I didn't point out then was that this would be my preferred implementation to read:

```
def sparse_table_elements(cells, columns, rows):
    ncells = len(cells)
    non_zeros = list()
    for nrow in range(0, ncells, columns):
         row = cells[nrow:nrow+columns]
         for ncol, cell in enumerate(row):
             if cell:
                 non_zeros.append([ncol, nrow, cell])
    return non_zeros
```

I've not tested it, but I can make sense of it. There are a couple of things that jump out at me as being *potential* inefficiencies. Recomputing the Cartesian product of two constant monotonically "boring" indices has got to be expensive:

```
itertools.product(xrange(self.rows), xrange(self.columns))
```

you then use the results `[(0, 0), (0, 1), ...]` to do single element indexing from your source:

```
stream_data[column + row * self.rows]
```

which is also more costly than handling larger slices as the "Jon's" implementation does.

Generators are not some secret sauce that guarantee efficiency. In this particular case, with 135kb of data that has already been read into core, a poorly constructed generator does seem to be costing you. If you want concise matrix operations, use [APL](http://www.youtube.com/watch?fmt=18&gl=GB&hl=en-GB&v=a9xAKttWgP4); if you want readable code, don't strive for rabid minimization in Python.

Comment: Furthermore the "single element slicing" you refer to -- what I would simply call indexed access to `stream_data` -- is actually done _twice_ in the generator/list comp version.

Answer (score 2):

You can trivially rewrite Jon's solution as a generator:

```
def create_ZS_data(self):
    self.ZS_data = ([colno, rowno, col]
                    for rowno, cols in enumerate(self.stream_data[i:i+self.columns]
                                                 for i in xrange(0, len(self.stream_data), self.columns))
                    for colno, col in enumerate(cols)
                    if col)
```

I would strongly expect this to behave the same as Jon's loop-based solution, demonstrating that the difference in performance is down to mid-scale details of algorithm implementation.